# Standalone year inputs with CakePHP 2.x FormHelper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, form-helpers

I am using CakePHP 2.10.20 for a legacy project that requires a field to store a year. So no days or months are needed, just years. I have tried to use the MySQL YEAR field type, as well as an INT(4).

I'm using the FormHelper to create a year input as following ...

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.test_year', [
  'type' => 'date',
  'dateFormat' => 'Y',
  'minYear' => date('Y'),
  'maxYear' => date('Y') + 1
]);
```

After saving the request data contains an array for the User.test_year field which looks like ...

```
array(
  'User' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'test_year' => array(
      'year' => '2020'
    )
  )
)
```

CakePHP always uses the array format for dates. When I usually debug a full date field (so year + month + day) in the beforeValidate() callback, it is already converted to the proper string format. However, when I try to debug this year-only field in beforeValidate(), it is still formatted as the same array.

Therefore, upon saving, I am confronted with a PHP notice and a MySQL error ...

```
Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 2220]

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

SQL Query: UPDATE `my_database`.`users` SET `id` = 1, `test_year` = Array, `modified` = '2020-04-14 23:10:32' WHERE `my_database`.`users`.`id` = '1'
```

Clearly the year in the array is not being converted into a proper string prior to being inserted into the database. I've also tried to use the FormHelper::year() method instead of the generic FormHelper::input(), but this does not change anything.

Really curious to learn what I'm doing wrong or overlooking, so thumbs up in advance to any CakePHP aficionados willing to point me in the right way.

Stay safe and thanks!

Comment: The `year` method just makes a specially-named select field with the years as options. Why not ignore it entirely and make your own select with those options, saving it in an int column?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We also have thought of that, but this leaves us wondering why the FormHelper actually offers methods such as year(), month() and day(). We use a customised FormHelper that extends the default FormHelper::input() method in order to add additional CSS classes as we require them. So we would like to be able to continue using that. Just want to make sure that we stay true to the framework and fully explore what is already available, prior to developing additional functionality.

Comment: My impression is that `year`, `month` and `day` functions are mainly meant for internal use, but also exposed in order to let people do things like create forms with just year and month fields visible and day set to 1, break them out into a different layout, or the like.

Comment: I'm starting to think the same. I'll keep the question open for a little while longer, but thanks to help me face reality ;-)

Comment: Something else struck me as being odd. How come that the FormHelper allows the use of FormHelper::input('Model.field', ['type' => 'year']), if the year is not meant to be submitted on its own? Hopefully I'm missing something, else it seems to be quite an odd design choice to expose it.

Comment: Other than the reasons that I gave above?

Comment: Just struck me as odd, but you're right. Had a chat with Mark Scherer who also upvoted your initial comment, confirming that that is the way to go. So thanks again for chiming in, we'll have to settle for that approach then!